# How to create a root for a click button angularjs

Tags: angularjs, redirect

I want to move to another page by clicking a button  here is my code :

```
var app= angular.module("MyUser",[]);
app.controller("UtilisateurControleur",function($scope,$http)
{$scope.list=[];
    $scope.Utilisateur=[];
    $scope.i=0;
      $scope.login = function(user) {

    $http.get("/allU").success(function(response) {
        $scope.list = response;
        $scope.nameList = [];
        var a=response.length;
        angular.forEach($scope.list,function(Obj,val){

            if (user.login===Obj.login && user.password===Obj.password)
            {
                console.log("Hi "+Obj.nom+" You are in the system");
            }
```

after the if i want to pass to a html page : /page.html. how i can resolve it

Answer (score 0):

inject $ngRoute too app module and $location to the controller , then try below

```
$location.path( '/page')
```

and in the app.config you can use the code below

```
$routProvider.when ('/page',{
     templateUrl :  '/page.html';
})
```

Comment: please see the response that i wrote

Comment: I told you you have to inject $location after $scope in the controller
`app.controller("UtilisateurControleur",function($scope,$http, $location)`

Comment: I added the $location but with click I could not be redirected to the new page.

Comment: yes the url of the page is : http://localhost:8181/pages/Accueil.html so the url that i added :/pages/Accueil.html

Comment: when i use $window.location.href i obtain the new page so the link is correct . but i want to use routeprovider because i use parameters exchanged between the pages

Comment: Please check my last answer ,

Comment: in your js File you inserted , you have misspell, $routProvider is wrong `$routeProvider.when ('/page',{
         templateUrl :  '/pages/Accueil.html';`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular [`$window`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window):

```
$window.location.href = '/index.html';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = angular.module('MyUser', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routProvider.when ('/page',{
         templateUrl :  '/pages/Accueil.html';
    })
  }]);


app.controller("UtilisateurControleur",function($scope,$http,$location)
{$scope.list=[];
    $scope.Utilisateur=[];
    $scope.i=0;
      $scope.login = function(user) {

    $http.get("/allU").success(function(response) {
        $scope.list = response;
        $scope.nameList = [];
        var a=response.length;
        angular.forEach($scope.list,function(Obj,val){

            if (user.login===Obj.login && user.password===Obj.password)
            {$location.path( '/page');
                console.log("Hi "+Obj.nom+" You are in the system");
            }

            });
});


      };

});
```

This is the code of my controller , i didn't find the problem.